# ROR - nil class on index but not on show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, null, associations

I've been trying to get the answer to this problem but without any luck. I guess it's an association problem and probably a rookie mistake (I'm one).
This is the functionality:
I need to create packs of beers for specific profiles (I know everything sounds fun with beers but it's killing me)

I have 3 models:

A beer model:

```
class Beer < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PermissionsConcern
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :ratings
  has_many :users, through: :ratings
  has_many :packs
end
```

A profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packs
end
```

A Pack model:

```
class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beer
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

This is the packs_controller

```
class PacksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pack, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @packs = Pack.all
end

def show
end

def edit
  @beers = Beer.all #Implementación incompleta. Revisar Filtros
  @profiles = Profile.all
end

def create
  @pack = Pack.new(pack_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @pack.save
      format.html { redirect_to @pack, notice: 'Pack was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @pack.update(pack_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @pack, notice: 'Pack was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
     end
  end
end
...

private
  def set_pack
    @pack = Pack.find(params[:id])
  end

  def pack_params
    params.require(:pack).permit(:delivery_date, :profile_id, :beer_id, :status)
  end
end
```

With this configuration I have the following situation:

in the Index view I do

```
@packs.each do |p|
p.beer.name #works fine
p.profile.name #brings an "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" message
end
```

In the show view I do:

```
@pack.beer.name #works fine.
@pack.profile.name #WORKS FINE ALSO
```

I tried to do it in the console and the results are the same:

```
Pack.last.profile.name # works fine

Pack.all # works and shows the profile_id correctly.

packs = Pack.all
packs.each do |p|
print p.beer.name #works fine
print p.profile.name #nil class again
end
```

Just in case I'm including the Schema:

```
create_table "beers", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",               limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
  t.string   "beer_type",          limit: 255
end

create_table "packs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date     "delivery_date"
  t.integer  "profile_id",    limit: 4
  t.integer  "beer_id",       limit: 4
  t.integer  "status",        limit: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
end

add_index "packs", ["beer_id"], name: "index_packs_on_beer_id", using: :btree
add_index "packs", ["profile_id"], name: "index_packs_on_profile_id", using: :btree

create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "ibu_range",  limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  t.string   "name",       limit: 255
end


add_foreign_key "packs", "beers"
add_foreign_key "packs", "profiles"
end
```

I tried to explain the situation as detailed as possible. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you also add the update action, so we can see how you are saving the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the packs may not have profile?

Since you are using console, try this:

```
Pack.all.select{|item| item.profile.nil?}.size
```

If size>0 and you don't want this, then please add `validates :profile, presence: true`.

Comment: Thanks!! I had one item.profile.nil? true and that was messing things up. This was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot!!